# C string and hex characters

Tags: c, c-strings

Can anyone explain what is happening in this code?

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void f(const char * str) {
      printf("%d\n", str[4]);
    }

    int main() {
      f("\x03""www""\x01""a""\x02""pl");
      f("\x03www\x01a\x02pl");
      return 0;
    }
```

why output is?

```
    1
    26
```

Comment: Because in the fifth place in these strings characters have an ascii value of `1` and `26`.

Comment: Use `printf("%s", str)` to print a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is with `"\x01""a"` versus `"\x01a"`, and the fact that the hex->char conversion and the string concatenation occur during different phases of lexical processing.

In the first case, the hexadecimal character is scanned and converted prior to concatenating
the strings, so the first character is seen as `\x01`. Then the "a" is
concatenated, but the hex->char conversion has already been performed,
and it's not re-scanned after the concatenation, so you get two letters
`\x01` and `a`.

In the second case, the scanner sees `\x01a` as a single character,
with ASCII code 26.

Answer (score 3):

In C, characters specified in hex (like `"\x01"`) can have more than two digits. In the first case, `"\x01""a"` is character 1, followed by 'a'. In the second case, `"\x01a"`, that's character 0x1a, which is 26.

Comment: thank you 
is there any way for writing 0x01 in string literal that prevent this bug?

Comment: Sure, either `"\x01""a"` or `"\x01\x61"`.